# how to seprate returns in xquery?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xquery, return-value, xquery-sql

As can be understood from the question which is:

```
Retrieve a nonredundant list of dancer ids and names of those dancers who
took part in the Auckland 2008 competition. Sort by @dancer_id. The output
of your query should conform to the following DTD:
<!ELEMENT Auckland_2008_Dancers (she_dancers,
he_dancers)>
<!ELEMENT she_dancers (Dancer)+>
<!ELEMENT Dancer EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST Dancer id CDATA #REQUIRED name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT he_dancers (Dancer)+>
```

the output I think should look like:

```
    <Auckland_2008_Dancers>
                <she_dancers>
                  <Dancer id="d6006" name="Sally Ann"/>
                </she_dancers>
                <she_dancers>
                  <Dancer id="d5005" name="Mimi"/>
                </she_dancers>
                <she_dancers>
                  <Dancer id="d1001" name="Anny"/>
                </she_dancers>
                <he_dancers>
                  <Dancer id="d9009" name="Gordon"/>
                </he_dancers>
                <he_dancers>
                  <Dancer id="d9008" name="Dimitrij"/>
                </he_dancers>         
                <he_dancers>
                  <Dancer id="d7007" name="James"/>
                </he_dancers>
                <he_dancers>
                  <Dancer id="d8007" name="Paul"/>
                </he_dancers>
        </Auckland_2008_Dancers>
```

But my code which is:

```
let $c:=fn:doc("/db/Zahra/dancingCompetitions_XQuery_15.xml")/dancingCompetitions/Competition[contains(@date,"2008") and @place="Auckland"]/Dance/dancePair
let $c2:=fn:doc("/db/Zahra/dancingCompetitions_XQuery_15.xml")/dancingCompetitions/Pairs/Pair
let $h:=fn:doc("/db/Zahra/dancingCompetitions_XQuery_15.xml")/dancingCompetitions/Dancers/he_dancers/Dancer
let $s:=fn:doc("/db/Zahra/dancingCompetitions_XQuery_15.xml")/dancingCompetitions/Dancers/she_dancers/Dancer

for $c3 in distinct-values($c/@ref_pair)
let $m := $c2[@pair_id = $c3]

return
<Auckland_2008_Dancers>


{
for $c5 in $m/she/@ref_she_dancer
let $c6 := $s[@dancer_id=$c5]
order by $c6/@dancer_id

return

<she_dancers>
<Dancer id="{$c6/@dancer_id}"  name="{$c6/Name}"/>
</she_dancers>
}


{
for $c4 in $m/he/@ref_he_dancer
let $c7 := $h[@dancer_id=$c4]
order by $c7/@dancer_id

return
<he_dancers>
<Dancer id="{$c7/@dancer_id}"  name="{$c7/Name}"/>
</he_dancers>
}
</Auckland_2008_Dancers>
```

produces:

```
<Auckland_2008_Dancers>
    <she_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d5005" name="Mimi"/>
    </she_dancers>
    <he_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d7007" name="James"/>
    </he_dancers>
</Auckland_2008_Dancers>
<Auckland_2008_Dancers>
    <she_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d6006" name="Sally Ann"/>
    </she_dancers>
    <he_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d9008" name="Dimitrij"/>
    </he_dancers>
</Auckland_2008_Dancers>
<Auckland_2008_Dancers>
    <she_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d1001" name="Anny"/>
    </she_dancers>
    <he_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d8007" name="Paul"/>
    </he_dancers>
</Auckland_2008_Dancers>
<Auckland_2008_Dancers>
    <she_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d6006" name="Sally Ann"/>
    </she_dancers>
    <he_dancers>
        <Dancer id="d9009" name="Gordon"/>
    </he_dancers>
</Auckland_2008_Dancers>
```

what shoiuld I do?
how should i correct it?
I have tried so many things to seprate returns from for and some produced same result and some gave errors.

Comment: For future questions, please make sure to include example input. Furthermore, make sure to use reasonable, descriptive variable names (all over the code, always). You might be able to understand what's going on right now, but not any more in two weeks, not your instructor and if you're into larger projects, nobody will understand anything any more.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<Auckland_2008_Dancers>` element outside of the loop.

```
let (: snip :)
return <Auckland_2008_Dancers>{
  for $c3 in distinct-values($c/@ref_pair)
  let $m := $c2[@pair_id = $c3]
  return
    (: snip :)
  }</Auckland_2008_Dancers>
```

Comment: Obviously I didn't copy all your code, including the first `let` statements. These would require a `return` statement, did you forget this?